# Does $g(f(x))$ imply $g(x)$?

Tags: calculus, functions

If $g$ is a function of $f(x)$ does this imply that $g$ is a function of $x$?

If yes, am I allowed to write the chain rule as:

$$\frac{{d[g(f[x])]}}{{dx}} = \frac{{d[g(x)]}}{{d[f(x)]}} \cdot \frac{{d[f(x)]}}{{dx}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaerbdXwyZnxAJfgBGCuyYfwBV5gzaerbtrvsybst
% HrhAaeXatLxBI9gBaerbnfgDOPuy49vtHrhAaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLD
% harqqtubsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea
% 0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0Firpepe
% KkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaGadiWadaqaaqaafeGaayaabaWbaaGcbaWa
% aSaaaeaacaWGKbGaai4waiaadEgacaGGOaGaamOzaiaacUfacaWG4b
% GaaiyxaiaacMcacaGGDbaabaGaamizaiaadIhaaaGaeyypa0ZaaSaa
% aeaacaWGKbGaai4waiaadEgacaGGOaGaamiEaiaacMcacaGGDbaaba
% GaamizaiaacUfacaWGMbGaaiikaiaadIhacaGGPaGaaiyxaaaacqGH
% flY1daWcaaqaaiaadsgacaGGBbGaamOzaiaacIcacaWG4bGaaiykai
% aac2faaeaacaWGKbGaamiEaaaaaaa!664A!
$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you wanted to write $g(f(x))$ instead of $g(x)$, then it's fine.

Comment: Hm, I don't know where to begin. Probably here: "a function *of* something" is nothing more than convenient slang, it's not really a well-defined term. The normal unambiguous term is "a map from set $A$ to set $B$". So the phrase "$g$ is a function of $f(x)$" doesn't really mean anything, at least not without further explanations.

Comment: $a$ is a function of $b$ means that `a depends on b`. If now `b depends on c` then, obviously `c affects b` and, thus, ultimately `determines a`. I think that $y=gf$ is called *a composition*. [In mathematics, function composition is the pointwise application of one function to another to produce a third function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to write the chain rule as
$$
\frac{\mathrm d[g(f(x))]}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm d[g(f(x))]}{\mathrm d[f(x)]}\cdot\frac{\mathrm d[f(x)]}{\mathrm dx}.
$$
The first term just means "differentiate $g(f(x))$ with respect to $f(x)$", i.e. pretend $f(x)$ is the independent variable, then fix your error by multiplying with how $f(x)$ changes with $x$, i.e. $\mathrm d[f(x)]/\mathrm dx$. That's exactly how the chain rule works.

I think you are confusing $g$ with $g\circ f$. Those are two different maps. This confusion may arise from sloppy notation, like the notation often found in physics, where $g$ and $g(y)$ are used interchangably for a quantity $g$ that depends on another quantity $y$. A good notation get's rid of this confusion by focusing on the **maps** and their respective **domains** and **ranges** instead of quantities and what they depend on.

In this case the maps are $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y\to Z$ and $g\circ f:X\to Z$, where $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are sets. So $f$ takes an element of the set $X$ to the set $Y$ which might then be mapped to an element in $Z$ by applying $g$. Using $f'$ and $g'$ for the derivatives with respect to the only independent variable each of these functions have, the chain rule is written as
$$ (g\circ f)'(x) = g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x) = (g'\circ f)(x)\cdot f'(x).$$

Comment: I am familiar with your notation. Please, check how I've written the rule. I wrote $d[g(x)]$ not $d[g(f[x])]$.

Comment: In that case: No, that's wrong. Plugging $x$ directly into $g$ may not even work, since $x$ is in the domain of $f$ not in the domain of $g$.

Comment: I added a paragraph to my answer explaining a possible source of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In short: Yes you may, but if you have more variables it becomes a mess. You should name the variable differently to emphasize that these come from a different set:

$$g \circ f : \mathbb R \ni x \stackrel{f(x)}\rightarrow \mathbb R \ni y \stackrel{g(y)}\rightarrow \mathbb R$$

Thus, for practical reasons, I recommend writing
$$\def\d{{\rm d}} \frac\d{\d x} g(f(x)) = \frac\d{\d y} g(f(x)) \cdot \frac\d{\d x}f(x)$$
This also saves on the parentheses, since the variable $y$ means to differentiate $g$ and *evaluate* at $f(x)$. A more complete notation would be
$$\left.\frac\d{\d t}(g\circ f(t))\right|_{t=x} = \left.\frac\d{\d s} g(s)\right|_{s=f(x)} \cdot \left.\frac\d{\d t} f(t)\right|_{t=x}$$

Comment: Just to make sure. Did you notice that I've written $d[g(x)]$ and not $d[g(f[x])]$ in the chain rule?

Comment: @AhmedAli Yes, I did. But if you try to do this with a multivarable function and higher-order derivatives (Say $\Delta f\circ g$ where $g : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m, f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$), it _will_ get really messy this way (i.e. naming the variables the same). That was what I wanted to point out. Also, in your notation $x\in{\rm dom}(f)$ and $x\in{\rm dom}(g)$ implicitly, so the two functions need to have the same domain or you "overload" $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is a function of $b$ means that `a depends on b`. If now `b depends on c` then, obviously `c affects b` and, thus, ultimately `a depends on c`. I think that y=gf is called *a composition*. [In mathematics, function composition is the pointwise application of one function to another to produce a third function. Intuitively, if z is a function g of y and y is a function f of x, then z is a function of x.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)